# Swagger UI retrieve the parameter Wrong

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, webapi

I want let Employee Sign Up and Sign In using username and password (1:1 relation). but have some error in Swagger UI it which the the parameter check the photo for more info: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sok08.png) [and the parameter I want username and pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxHLf.png)

There is no errors in the code I tried to change AuthController.cs multiple time but still the same.

There are another classes but I think these are related this issue.

model
employee.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\+222\d{7}$")]
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string? Department { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

User.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

DBcontext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(u => u.Employee)
            .WithOne(e => e.User)
            .HasForeignKey<Employee>(e => e.Id);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Authcontroller.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EmployeeAPI.Models;

namespace EmployeeAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/auth")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public AuthController(DataContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _context = context;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        // User registration
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] User userRegistration)
        {
            if (await _context.Users.AnyAsync(u => u.Username == userRegistration.Username))
            {
                return BadRequest("Username is already taken.");
            }

            var user = new User
            {
                Username = userRegistration.Username,
                Password = PasswordHash.HashPassword(userRegistration.Password)
            };

            _context.Users.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok("User registered successfully.");
        }

        // User login
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] User userLogin)
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Username == userLogin.Username);

            if (user == null || !PasswordHash.VerifyPassword(userLogin.Password, user.Password))
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid username or password.");
            }

            var token = GenerateJwtToken(user);

            return Ok(new { Token = token });
        }

        private string GenerateJwtToken(User user)
        {
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                signingCredentials: credentials
            );

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
    }

}
```

Employee.cs

```
using EmployeeAPI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EmployeeAPI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/employees")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public EmployeeController(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/employees
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<PagedResult<Employee>>> GetEmployees(int page = 1, int pageSize = 10, string department = null)
        {
            var username = User.Identity.Name;

            var query = _context.Employees.AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(department))
            {
                query = query.Where(e => e.Department == department);
            }

            query = query.Where(e => e.User.Username == username);

            var totalItems = await query.CountAsync();
            var employees = await query.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();

            return new PagedResult<Employee>
            {
                Page = page,
                PageSize = pageSize,
                TotalItems = totalItems,
                Data = employees
            };
        }



// Soft delete an employee
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SoftDeleteEmployee(int id)
{
    var username = User.Identity.Name;
    
    var employee = await _context.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id && e.User.Username == username);
    
    if (employee == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    
    employee.IsDeleted = true;
    employee.UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return NoContent();
}



// Update an employee
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEmployee(int id, Employee updatedEmployee)
{
    var username = User.Identity.Name;

    var existingEmployee = await _context.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id && e.User.Username == username);

    if (existingEmployee == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // Update the properties you want to change
    existingEmployee.FirstName = updatedEmployee.FirstName;
    existingEmployee.LastName = updatedEmployee.LastName;
    existingEmployee.PhoneNumber = updatedEmployee.PhoneNumber;
    existingEmployee.Department = updatedEmployee.Department;
    existingEmployee.UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContent();
}

    }
}
```

Comment: The `User` field is at least one problem.  It's a complex type, not a string.  That's the second error in your error screen shot.  You might need to do some work on that field.

Answer (score 0):

If you explain the red lines below properties, it is spell checker of your platform and is ignorable.

Your code is true and if your code runs without any error, dont note to the red lines and go.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to separate the request model and the entity model. Similarly, to return data in response use DTO.

```
public class RegisterUserRequest
{
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;

    public string? FirstName { get; set; }

    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\+222\d{7}$")]
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string? Department { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterUserRequest registerUserRequest)
{
    if (await _context.Users.AnyAsync(u => u.Username == registerUserRequest.Username))
    {
        return BadRequest("Username is already taken.");
    }

    var user = new User
    {
        Username = registerUserRequest.Username,
        Password = PasswordHash.HashPassword(registerUserRequest.Password)
    };

    var employee = new Employee
    {
        FirstName = registerUserRequest.FirstName,
        LastName = registerUserRequest.LastName,
        PhoneNumber = registerUserRequest.PhoneNumber,
        Department = registerUserRequest.Department,
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
        UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
        IsDeleted = false,
        User = user
    };

    _context.Users.Add(user);
    _context.Employees.Add(employee);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok("User registered successfully.");
}
```

You should not get the below property in an API request.

```
public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
```